# How can I get my TenantId from Azure AD with ClaimsPrincipal?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity

I have a little problem in my code. I want to get my `TenantID` but the field is empty (null)? How do I fix it?

Did I forget something here?

```
public static string GetMyTenantID(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    return principal.Claims
                    .Where(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid")
                    .Single().Value;
}
```

Comment: What is the `.NET` version you are using ?

Comment: Are you running this code `locally` ?

Comment: the .NET Version is 4.8 and yes this code is running locally :(

Comment: Even if I host the web application in Azure, I don't get my Teenant ID. I need to fix this in code

Comment: Is your application registered in the `Azure Active Directory` ?

Comment: yes is already registered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252527/discussion-between-harshitha-and-zaniolo10).